# Chef + InSpec using only_if for users

Tags: ruby, rspec, chef-infra, chef-recipe, inspec

I need to go through a list of users and determine whether they are in a locked state, I can do this just fine but my issue is that I don't know how inspec will let me ignore users on my list that don't exist on the operating system. I've tried a few different methods using only_if (including below) with no luck.

Here is my code below:

```
system_accounts = [
'user1'
'user2'
'user3'

system_accounts.each do |name|
  only_if command("getent passwd #{name}") do
   describe command("passwd -S #{name}").stdout.split[1] do
     it { should match /LK|NP|NL/ }
     end
   end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can only use `only_if` and similar APIs from inside a `control` block. You would probably want to use the `user` InSpec resource for this in the first place but also check out the `users` API.